# SQL replace value

Tags: sql, replace

I have some data stored in a table about a client's language preference but it is stored as an integer where 8 = english and 9 = french etc. The reason for this I assume is that the integers are keys in another table that links them to the string describing them.

Unfortunately I only have access to the first table and not the other one or it would be a simple matter of doing a JOIN so is it possible to write a SELECT query that maps the 8 to English and 9 to French and so on?

I'm imagining something like this..

```
SELECT clientName, FUNCTION(languagePreference, ((8, "English"), (9, "French"))) 
FROM table
```

So instead of this..

```
clientName languagePreference

Dave          8    
Emmanuelle    9    
Luc           9    
John          8
```

I get this...

```
clientName languagePreference

Dave         English
Emmanuelle   French
Luc          French
John         English
```

Comment: also anyone know how to represent tabular data in StackOverflow posts?

Comment: There are certainly options to do the inline conversion as you describe above, but it will likely be server specific.  What DBMS are you using?

Comment: This particular situation needs to work using TSQL on SQL Server 2008 but it would also be useful to know how to do this in MySQL

Comment: Re tabular data: the most common approach is to format it in a code block and use spaces to make everything line up, since code formatting uses a fixed width for all characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TSQL:`

```
SELECT clientName, 
  CASE languagePreference
       WHEN 8 THEN 'English'
       WHEN 9 THEN 'French'
       ... --Go on like this if you have more languagePreference keys
  END as languagePreference
FROM table
```

Answer (score 1):

Using TSQL, use a `CASE`

```
SELECT clientName, 
       CASE WHEN (languagePreference=8) THEN 
               'English' 
       ELSE 
            CASE WHEN (languagePreference=9) THEN
                'French'
            ELSE
                'Unknown'
            END
       END as languagePreference
FROM table
```

Comment: You can put everything in a `single CASE` no need for nesting

Comment: Yes just saw that, good to know! This is mainly the reason why I interract on SO...learn!